# NumPy complex array and callbacks

Tags: python, numpy, callback

I want to extend this question [How to access arrays passed to ctypes callbacks as numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702372/how-to-access-arrays-passed-to-ctypes-callbacks-as-numpy-arrays) to the case of complex numbers.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import ctypes
import os.path

array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.complex128, ndim=1, flags='CONTIGUOUS')

callback_func = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    None,            # return
    ctypes.POINTER(np.complex128), # x
    ctypes.c_int     # n
)

libtest = npct.load_library('libtest', os.path.dirname(__file__))
libtest.callback_test.restype = None
libtest.callback_test.argtypes = [array_1d_double, ctypes.c_int, callback_func]


@callback_func
def callback(x, n):
    x = npct.as_array(x, (n,))
    print("x: {0}, n: {1}".format(x[:n], n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([20, 13, 8, 100, 1, 3], dtype=np.complex128)
    libtest.callback_test(x, x.shape[0], callback)
```

**test.c**

```
#include <complex.h>

typedef void (*callback_t)(
    void* *x,
    int n
);

void callback_test(void** x, int n, callback_t callback) {
    _Complex double* cx = (_Complex double*)x;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        cx[j] = cx[j] / i;
                }

                callback(x, n);
        }
}
```

Gives me:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
>       ctypes.POINTER(np.complex128), # x
>   TypeError: *type* must have storage info

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctypes can't handle numpy types directly. Thus "POINTER(np.complex128)" results in an error. You could use the ndpointer result as the type and remove the shape argument in as_array. This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import ctypes
import os.path

array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.complex128, ndim=1, flags='CONTIGUOUS')

callback_func = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    None,            # return
    array_1d_double,
    ctypes.c_int     # n
)

libtest = npct.load_library('libtest', os.path.dirname(__file__))
libtest.callback_test.restype = None
libtest.callback_test.argtypes = [array_1d_double, ctypes.c_int, callback_func]


@callback_func
def callback(x, n):
    x._shape_ = (n,)
    x = npct.as_array(x)
    print("x: {0}, n: {1}".format(x[:n], n))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([20, 13, 8, 100, 1, 3, 11, 12, 13], dtype=np.complex128)
    libtest.callback_test(x, x.shape[0], callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does not work when `shape(6,)` is not set though (so I can't work with different array sizes).

Comment: I added a "hack" to assign the shape to the private _shape_ attribute of the returned ndpointer. I think there should be a cleaner way to do this, but at least this works for my numpy version.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in my application. I'm no expert of NumPy, could you please let me know what are the danger of using your "hack" ?

Comment: A general python convention is that attributes starting with a single underscore are considered "private" and thus might change their sematics or even vanish in the future, without beeing noticed in a changelog.